# how can i add a empty list to each element of list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have list like `mylist=['a','b','c',1,2,3]`. iterating through each element of list, I wanna update this list as `mylist=[['a',[]],['b',[]],['c',[]],[1,[]],[2,[]],[3,[]]]`. the important thing is that each list associated with elements of mylist should not point to the same list. i.e., `mylist[0][1]` and `mylist[1][1]` should not point to the same list. So that i can modify each sub list independently. Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @dspencer, i was not thinking about list comprehensions . i was just   defining a new empty list each time and assigning it to elements of original list 1 by one. thanks for providing this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved easily using a list comprehension along your original `myList`. By adding an empty list on each iteration, there is no problem with sharing a reference to the same list, which you seem to be concerned about.

```py
myList = [[element, []] for element in myList]
```

Comment: how can i add a tuple in the same way inplace of empty list

Comment: Given that tuples are immutable, this is not likely to be very useful. Are you sure that's what you want? If you have a specific tuple to add, then it can be done.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, could you please accept it?

Comment: @MrSukhe, please don't ask new questions in the comment section. If this answer addresses your original question in a satisfying way, you should mark it accepted. If you still have question you cannot solve yourself through research, then post a new question.

Comment: i will keep this in mind @trincot . i m new to stackoverflow. Thanks again